# Is there any scriptural basis for the claim that Europeans/White people are vanaras and belong to Hanuman's lineage?

Tags: puranas, ramayana, hanuman, itihasa, vanaras

According to some Europeans, they were treated as **untouchables** in the 17th century in India. According to the Nepali civil code of 1854 they were "Pani Na Chalne Chhoichhito Haalnu Naparne" or **Water-unacceptable** but touchable people - Mlechhas. And in traditional settings I have often heard them being referred to as **"bandar" or monkey**  In fact, I heard one saint say that they are from **Hanuman's lineage or Vanaras**. Later I also found on the internet that bandars supposedly had a great **Vanara Kingdom of Central Asia and Europe.**

*Is there any scriptural reference to this? Someone please find it!! Even Europeans admit that they are from apes*

According to other theory god has created humans by color (Varn) but I think we all know that.

Comment: Mlecchas evolved from apes (australopithecus, homo erectus, etc.) whereas chatur-varna Indians descended from devatas.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Technically just my opinion, but I believe that we are descended through evolution from the last universal common ancestor as expected in science, but that last universal common ancestor is itself descended from ancient humans. It fits nicely and explains a lot of details, especially with a time skip when no new humans are around.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does scripture describe the origin of Mlecchas and outcastes?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32511/does-scripture-describe-the-origin-of-mlecchas-and-outcastes)

Comment: @sv. No actually I am asking specifically about Whites or Europeans only. They are said to come from Vanaras after Lord Ramjis time so it is not duplicate.

Comment: It is generally understood that non-Indians/non-Hindus are all mlecchas so using "Europeans" and "White people" doesn't make them non-mleccha according to Hindu scripture. So your current question is a subset of the other one. To prevent closure, you need a better title, something like: "Is there any scriptural basis for the claim that Europeans/White people are vanaras and belong to Hanuman's lineage?"

Comment: Done. Thanks! :) @sv.